# Fetching data using PDO and get the data only once with its column names

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When using PDO to fetch values from a mysql database I get some redundant information, and I'm wondering why. The php function below returns the values as I want them to be returned. But if I return my result array, I get double values.

```
public function getNames($userid) {
        try {
            $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.parent::Database(), parent::User(), parent::Password());
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            var_dump("error: $e");
        }

        $sql = "SELECT ID, Name FROM cars WHERE userid =:UID and type=2";
        $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindParam(':UID', $userid);
        $sth->execute();

        $result = $sth->fetchAll(); //fetches all results where there's a match

        $result2 = array();
        foreach($result as $res)
            $result2[] = array("ID"=>$res["ID"], "Name"=>$res["Name"]);

        return $result2;
    }
```

$Result returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [0] => 2
            [Name] => Volvo
            [1] => Volvo
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 8
            [0] => 8
            [Name] => Ford
            [1] => Ford
        )

)
```

$Result2 returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [Name] => Volvo
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 8
            [Name] => Ford
        )

)
```

Why is $result acting like this? Its like its fetching my data multiple times. Am I using the code wrong? If possible, I want to use the result of $result2 without specifying each return array - in case the table is getting edited at some point. Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the results both as an associative array and an indexed array.

To get only the associative array, you can use:

```
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```